# Перегрузка функций - выбор между типом параметра массива и указателя

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть два шаблона функции, одна из них принимает ссылку на массив char, вторая - указатель на char.
Если мы вызываем функцию, передавая ей в качестве параметра строковый литерал, то все работает как и ожидается - инстанцируется шаблон с параметром массива.

```
template <size_t n>
void f(const char (&)[n])
{
   std::cout << "-- char []" << std::endl;
}

template <typename>
void f(const char *)
{
   std::cout << "-- char *" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   f("abc");
   return 0;
}
```

**-- char []**

Но если мы добавим в параметры шаблонов тип элементов массива/указателя, то компилятор выдает ошибку неоднозначности выбора:

```
template <typename t, size_t n>
void f(const t (&)[n])
{
   std::cout << "-- char []" << std::endl;
}

template <typename t>
void f(const t *)
{
   std::cout << "-- char *" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   f("abc");
   return 0;
}
```

**a.cpp:63:8: error: call of overloaded ‘f(const char [4])’ is ambiguous**

Почему в данном случае компилятор не может выбрать функцию, и как это побороть?

Comment: Ну, побороть-то это нетрудно... Например, `f((const char*)"abc");` или  `f<char,4>("abc");`.

Answer (score 2):

В первом случае функция `f(const char *)` вообще не может быть вызвана без явного указания параметра шаблона, так как он не выводится из аргументов. А во втором - выводится, вот и получается неопределенность. Чтобы различить передачу массива и указателя, во втором случае указатель тоже нужно принимать по ссылке:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>

template <typename t, size_t n>
void f(t const ( & )[n])
{
   std::cout << "-- char []" << std::endl;
}

template <typename t>
void f(t const * const &)
{
   std::cout << "-- char *" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   f("abc");
   f(static_cast<char const *>("abc"));
   return 0;
}
```

> -- char []
> -- char *

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:15,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:15,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:15,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:15,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstddef.h%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+t,+size_t+n%3E%0Avoid+f(t+const+(%26)%5Bn%5D)%0A%7B%0A+++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22--+char+%5B%5D%22+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+t%3E%0Avoid+f(t+const+*+const+%26)%0A%7B%0A+++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22--+char+*%22+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A+++f(%22abc%22)%3B%0A+++f(static_cast%3Cchar+const+*%3E(%22abc%22))%3B%0A+++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.29120111731844,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g121,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+12.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:55.70879888268156,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Answer (score 2):

Встроенный тип строки как массив символов имеет способность автоматического преобразования типа на указатель на первую букву. Чтобы не было такой проблемы желательно использовать собственный тип без преобразования. И тогда заданную строку как массив передавать как свой тип.

```
# include <cstdlib>
# include <iostream>

template <typename t , size_t n >
struct   ConstArray {
  t const ( & a ) [ n ] ;
  ConstArray(t const ( & x ) [ n ]):a{x}{}
} ;

template <typename t ,size_t n>
void f(ConstArray<t,n> const & )
{
   std::cout << "-- char []" << std::endl;
}

template <typename t>
void f(const t *)
{
   std::cout << "-- char *" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    f("abc");
   f(ConstArray{"abc"});
   return 0;
}
```